# How to combine data from two raster layers in QGIS?

Tags: gis, raster, qgis, elevation

I am quite new to QGIS, and using version 3.4.5 Madeira.

I have one raster layer with 22 land-use classes for each pixel (25m resolution), and another raster layer with elevation data for each pixel (10m resolution), see screenshots.

My question is how to combine the data from those two layers?

The result should be a third raster layer with the land-use class AND elevation data for each pixel (25m resolution). For example, I want to know how many pixels with a certain land-use class are below or above 1000m elevation.

Thank you!

**land-use classes**

[image: land-use classes]

**elevation data**

[image: elevation data]